# jquery tools TABS - hiding DIV in the Tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

i'm using simple jQuery Tools Tabs

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

with this html:

```
<!-- the tabs --> 
                <ul class="tabs"> 
                    <li><a href="#">Passenger Record</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Annotations (10)</a></li> 
                </ul> 

                <!-- tab "panes" --> 
                <div class="panes"> 
                    <div>
                    First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"
                        <div class="NoShow">THIS DIV IS HIDDEN??</div>
                    </div> 
                    <div>Second tab content</div> 
                </div>
```

So the div with the class="NoShow" is hidden.  I believe it has to do with the javascript

```
("div.panes > div");
```

But I don't want the DIVs inside the DIV Tabs to be hidden??  How do i just hide the DIVs associated to the Tabs?

Comment: try giving the tab specific tabs some class name and change selector to `("div.panes > div.ClassName")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("div.panes > div");` refers only to direct children. The 'NoShow' div is a grandchild of 'panes'.

Try  `$("#NoShow")` instead -- it's faster, too, because you use an ID instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

the reason nested div could not be shown is you have got a css property

```
.panes div {
    display:none;
}
```

from the example of jquery tools:
http://jquerytools.org/media/css/tabs-panes.css